InertiaJS автоматически изменяет URL страницы
Есть приложение на Laravel+Vue. Установил InertiaJS, переделал под нее приложение. Всё нормально, однако в адресной строке сам по себе меняется URL страницы, к примеру:
"site.ru/v2/log-in?log-in="
К урлу сам автоматически добавляется query-параметр "?log-in=", название параметра соответствует роуту.
Понизил версию библиотеки inertiajs/inertia-laravel, и удивительно, что с ней меняться стал таким образом - вписываем "site.ru/v2/log-in", а он сам переходит по "site.ru/v2/v2/log-in", то есть вставляет от себя "v2".
Я не понимаем, в чем беда тут, надеюсь на какую-либо помощь или наводку
